Has reductive physicalism been falsified?
This answer to Does asking counterfactual questions about the context/conditions of one's birth presuppose the existence of souls? proposed an alternative view:

Alternative: Reductive physicalism
For reductive physicalism, the answer is trivial: you're "you" because
that's what your brain chemistry produces. It's similar to asking why
some object produces a particular smell instead of another smell (as
in why it generates certain particulates - the actual experience of
smell is a subjective experience that varies from one person to the
next), or why some object is magnetic and another isn't, or why some
object has a particular weight instead of another weight.
It's just a result of the stuff it's made of. Other things are made of
different stuff, and they therefore end up being different.
This also challenges our idea of identity. We tend to think of
consciousness as a single unit, and that we have "the same"
consciousness throughout our lives... even though we recognise that we
change - "I was a completely different person back then" is not an
uncommon saying. But if consciousness reduces to brain chemistry
(which constantly changes), then we can think of it more like a
computer. You might always broadly have the same parts, but you could
see wildly different things on the screen based on what programs you
have installed and what you have running and what's going on in
memory, and one computer behaves differently from another because much
of that is different and they may have different hardware.
There is of course a lot more to
say about the
philosophy of mind, and there are other non-dualist, mostly
physicalist, views.

In response, a commenter challenged this:

This answer assumes a false dichotomy between reductive physicalism and spiritual dualism. Reductive physicalism has been widely considered falsified, even among physicalists, due to the failure of the global reductive programme. See SEP, scientific reduction, section 5. Also philosophy of chemistry section 6: plato.stanford.edu/entries/chemistry/#CheRed The substantive similarity between people that allows us to develop Theory of Mind, and empathy, and realize "there but for luck go I" is a truth about our world, and must be accounted for in any ontologic theory.

I bolded the sentence "Reductive physicalism has been widely considered falsified, even among physicalists, due to the failure of the global reductive programme", which the commenter supported with a reference to SEP, Philosophy of Chemistry, in particular:

6. Chemical Reduction
One of the perennial topics in philosophy of science concerns inter-theoretic relations. In the course of
debating whether biology is reducible to the physical sciences or
whether psychology is reducible to biology, many philosophers assume
that chemistry has already been reduced to physics. In the past, this
assumption was so pervasive that it was common to read about
“physico/chemical” laws and explanations, as if the reduction of
chemistry to physics was complete. Although most philosophers of
chemistry would accept that there is no conflict between the sciences
of chemistry and physics (Needham 2010b), many would reject a stronger
unity thesis. Most believe that chemistry has not been reduced to
physics nor is it likely to be (see Le Poidevin 2005, for the opposite
view, and Hendry & Needham 2007, for a rejoinder).
When thinking about the question of reducibility in chemistry, it is
useful to break this question into two parts: The first, and more
familiar one to philosophers, concerns the relationship between
elements, atoms, molecules, and the fundamental particles of physics.
We might ask, “Are atomic and molecular species reducible to systems
of fundamental particles interacting according to quantum mechanics?”
A second, less familiar question concerns the relationship between the
macroscopic and microscopic descriptions of chemical substances. “Are
chemical substances reducible to molecular species?” Here, the main
question is whether all chemical properties that have been defined
macroscopically can be redefined in terms of the properties of atoms,
molecules, and their interactions.

Has reductive physicalism been falisifed, or at least are there compelling reasons to think it is very likely false?

Downvoters: explain the downvotes.

Yeah, they're not going to, especially because you didn't use the magic word.


please... (@JD)


Upvoted. It is a valid question, though the answer is no.

@keshlam - Why did you delete your answer?

@keshlam (It's always good to be open to learning, but I wouldn't be as inclined to take people's word for things. Just my 2 cents, anyway.)

We need to make a distinction between reductionism - the idea that sciences like chemistry, neuroscience, or sociology can in principle be reduced to physics - and the question of whether these sciences actually have been reduced to physics - meaning that scientists in chemistry, neuroscience, or sociology can begin with electrons, protons, neutrons, etc. and derive the results of their field purely based on the formulas of quantum mechanics (or any other fundamental physics theory). Obviously, in this sense, neuroscience and sociology have not been reduced to physics, but this is independent of whether they in principle can be.
When SEP says

Although most philosophers of chemistry would accept that there is no conflict between the sciences of chemistry and physics (Needham 2010b), many would reject a stronger unity thesis. Most believe that chemistry has not been reduced to physics nor is it likely to be

They are referring to the second sense; most philosophers of chemistry believe that there are aspects of chemistry theory that have not been completely grounded in physics theory. This does not mean most philosophers of chemistry are not reductionists.
Supporting this interpretation, the SEP article goes on to say:

If one thinks that reduction means deriving the phenomenon of the higher level exclusively from the lower level, then these arguments should settle the question of reduction. More than 80 years after the discovery of quantum mechanics, chemistry has not been reduced to it.

So yes, the SEP article is using the second sense (when it says that most philosophers of chemistry say that chemistry has not been reduced to physics). It goes on to explain how reductionists use the first sense:

First, reductionists can argue that there are no principled reasons that chemical phenomena have not been derived from quantum mechanics. The problem is a lack of computational power and appropriate approximation schemes, not anything fundamental. Schwarz (2007) has made this argument against Scerri, claiming that the electronic structure of atoms, and hence the Periodic Table, is in principle derivable from quantum mechanics. He believes that quantum chemistry’s inability to reduce chemical properties is simply a manifestation of the problems shared by all of the computationally complex sciences. Debate then turns to the plausibility of such “reducibility in principle” claims.


Despite the claim that chemistry has not been reduced to it, chemistry modelling is actually something quantum simulations have been EXTREMELY successful in. We can model many simple molecular compounds. We can't model a lot of complex compounds in QM, not because they're in principle impossible to model in QM, but because simulating QM takes a crap load of computing power. I'd wager the vast majority of physicists and chemists would agree that current evidence is sufficient to think that, yes, chemistry absolutely reduces to quantum physics.

In fact it's pretty safe to say that the reason why atoms bind in the way they do is precisely because of quantum interactions, and  explaining chemical bindings was one of the major inspirations for coming up with quantum theory in the first place.

@TKoL  the challenges to global reduction do not claim that nothing ever reduces.  Citing examples of successful reductions do not support the global claim, they are instead an example of confirmation bias in operation.  Science looks for REFUTATIONS, not CONFIRMATIONS.

Causative -- the failure to satisfy the theory of reduction, spelled out in the SEP article on scientific reductionism, is strong refuting evidence to the possibility, ever, of global reductionism being true of our world.  Invoking Quine-Duhem, that SOMEDAY we might find some way global reduction might not be refuted by what we think we know, is of course also the case for every other refuted conjecture in science.

@Dcleve my comments were not global but specific. The person i replied to mentioned chemistry specifically, i replied to that specifically,

@TKoL -- the person you are responding to is the SEP on the philosophy of chemistry.  The full text of the SEP section has not been quoted, as, contrary to the quote referenced, computational thruput is not the only problem for physics reductionism.  See:  "Bogaard argues that many key chemical concepts such as valence and bonding do not find a natural home in quantum mechanics." and  "If chemical entities such as molecules and ions end up being part of the physical ontology, [...] this was [...] simply the expansion of the ontology of physics to encompass the ontology of chemistry."

@Dcleve -- The refutations are pointing at increasingly smaller gaps where quantum chemistry doesn’t have the exact solution, yet. There’s really nothing to be found in these gaps other than incomplete descriptions. It is like saying that physics is wrong because we can’t (yet) explain dark matter. That doesn’t mean that physics is wrong. It doesn't mean physics doesn't work or that we better give up on physics. No, it means we have to work towards completion, or, and that is maybe the best we can do, get arbitrarily close to completion.

@Dcleve -- Bogaard wrote that in 1978, nearly fifty years ago... "If chemical entities such as molecules and ions end up being part of the physical ontology, [...] this was [...] simply the expansion of the ontology of physics to encompass the ontology of chemistry." Not sure what you are trying to say with that. I don't think it is controversial to say that the ontology of physics encompasses the ontology of chemistry. It is still practical, however, to distinguish the domains of physics and chemistry. What it means in principal and what it means in practice are different things.

@Dcleve: I think you and TKoL may be talking past one another. The issue here is that there are no identified counterexamples to reduction - there is no specific chemical compound, reaction, etc. that we have reason to believe is irreducible. Since everything that we have tried to reduce has either succeeded or proved intractable to evaluate, it is not unreasonable to assume that chemistry is (probably or defeasibly) reducible until a counterexample can be identified.

@Philomath — Molecules and ions are not elementary particles characterized in the Standard Model.  They are higher tier structures.  Reductionism is the view that one does not need the higher tier structures to describe reality.  IF one NEEDS to invoke higher tier structures to describe chemistry, then chemistry does not reduce to physics. The ontology of physics would NOT encompass the ontology of chemistry.  Saying that reduction succeeded when you just described in detail a failed test case, is bizarre!

@Kevin Nagel spelled out in detail the conditions needed to show reduction had occurred.  Some aspects of chemistry satisfy this criteria.  But see section 6 of SEP scientific reduction: “The most prominent argument against reductionism stems from the observation that straightforward reductions hardly ever occur. Hence, reductionism cannot be regarded as yielding a coherent picture of what actually goes on in science.“  Neither chemistry, nor any other field, even loosely approximate Nagel’s criteria.

A distinction needs to be made between the field of study of chemistry, which involves talks and papers and diagrams of molecules on paper, and the physical domain of chemistry, which involves the actual water molecules and hydrochloric acid molecules and so on. Reductionism is about the physical domain, not the field of study. It's not intended to yield a picture of what "goes on in science" (socially or academically). It's intended to yield a picture of what happens in reality, distinct from how we talk about it. This is the problem with Nagel's view.

@Dcleve "Reductionism is the view that one does not need the higher tier structures to describe reality" -- this is a question of practicality. Reductionism does NOT claim that there's no practical need to talk about the higher tier structures. There quite clearly are practical needs. Reductionism, instead, is the claim that higher level structures are the consequence of lower level processes. That's what it means to reduce something - to explain something higher as the result of something lower. If that can be done, then that's a successful reduction.

The guys over at physics stackexchange, who are much better equipped to answer this question, do not agree with what Dcleve is saying here. https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/810435/do-we-understand-chemistry-from-particle-physics -- Matt Hanson, professor of physical chemistry, says "it is better to think of the entire nature of chemistry as dictated by the principles of quantum mechanics".

If that's true - that quantum mechanics dictates all chemical behaviours - then it's ontologically true that chemistry reduces to QM, regardless of if we've been able to see that reduction through in large-scale practical cases. One must distinguish between ontological reduction and in-practice reduction - most physicists and chemists will agree that ontologically, chemistry follows from QM.

Falsification of reduction is ... literally impossible?
(but that's not a bad thing)
I agree with causative's answer that there are 2 senses of reduction, which I'd describe as: reduction we know about and reduction that exists in reality (whether we know it or not).
For reduction we know about, it may be possible to falsify local reduction to known causes. If have 2 systems, and we monitor every known cause in that system to show that all of those are the same, yet the systems behave differently, that would be falsification. But it may mean there is some cause outside of the small area we monitored and/or some unknown cause. That does more to falsify a particular understanding of how reality works, rather than falsifying the idea of reduction.
For reduction that exists in reality, it's unclear whether it's even conceptually possible to falsify that.
Reduction means that a system is nothing more than the sum of its parts. Reduction is heavily tied to the idea of cause-and-effect. If some system contains some effect or behaviour, there must be a cause (or a set of causes) for it.
If reduction is false, it would essentially mean that something happens spontaneously for no reason. To us, this would be indistinguishable from something having a cause we don't know. So even if we had such an event, we wouldn't be able to say reduction has been falsified. To say that would essentially be giving up.
If people said lightning and rain and droughts and floods are not reducible (to some extent), then we would never developed weather and climate models. If people said disease is not reducible, we would never have developed germ theory. If people said consciousness is not reducible, we would never have developed the fields of neuroscience and psychology, which contains countless meaningful and useful results.
* All of these examples are examples of things once (or still, by many) deemed "outside the physical", or caused by things outside the physical. So, while this section is generally not specific to the "physical", these are all excellent examples of why we shouldn't just label something as "non-physical" and then stop looking for a physical reduction. For all the times people have done that, we've shown plenty of those to be wrong, but we've never shown them to be right.
All of science is driven by wanting to know how things work, and what causes what, and then investigating and experimenting to figure that out. It's the practice of reduction.
Now, let's say we had something happen spontaneously for no (apparent) reason. Let's say some being materialised (seemingly) out of nothing from nowhere in front of our eyes (and we rule out hallucination). The most reasonable conclusion to draw from this would not be that there definitely isn't a reason. Rather, we might propose that our model of reality is incomplete or flawed. There might be some other laws we don't know or some other "realm". We would then investigate to try to figure out why that happened.
Maybe we never figure it out. At some point, it may indeed make sense to give up and spend time on other, more productive, things (maybe hoping future technology could give us the answers). It doesn't mean there is no cause, it just doesn't seem that we're likely to find one any time soon.
"It happened for no reason" essentially just means "we haven't found a reason yet". There is just a "gap" in our knowledge. And we should be okay with not knowing everything. But that doesn't mean we should insert a god or some other "supernatural" thing into that gap, merely because there is a gap.
Has there been a "failure of reduction"?
Well, reduction is an ever-expanding process. For "complete" reduction: Every new thing we discover in the universe would need to be reduced down through all scientific models and forces at various scales (e.g. biological, atomic, quantum, gravitational). Every interaction between things would similarly need to be reduced. Every new scientific model we apply at a different scale would need corresponding reductions to every model at every other scale for every single thing in the universe.
This seems to expect a complete all-encompassing understanding of everything, which doesn't seem like a reasonable demand.
Also, we've been at the practice of trying to reduce things for a minuscule fraction of the lifespan of the universe and the Earth. As one example, electron microscopes were invented less than 100 years ago.
If anything, I'd say we've been exceptionally effective at finding such reductions, at explaining how things work and breaking that down to interactions at various scales.
But that wouldn't stop people from coming along, handwaving away all that progress, picking out 1 thing or another, and saying "look, we haven't fully reduced this thing yet, therefore this has all been one massive failure". Within the context of a single lifespan, it's easy to feel like we're not making much progress, that we're stuck. This is especially the case if one isn't working on the forefront of increasing humanity's knowledge and/or if your exposure to that is limited. If you look back across hundreds or thousands of years of progress across human history, it's easy to think the dozen or so years you've been around doesn't have much progress by comparison (because it's just so much less time, and we're not currently living through one of the rare instances of fundamental shifts in our understanding of the world... well, except maybe we are still on the tail end of quantum physics, and there's maybe also AI research).
But we keep making progress. There may be some fundamental limits to what we're able to model and reduce, given the limits of what we're able to observe and computational limits. But I don't see much reason to think we're at that point yet. Maybe modern quantum mechanics is the best and smallest subatomic-scale model we ever develop. But I wouldn't put my money on that (although I would say we don't currently have good reason to accept that there is anything "beneath" quantum mechanics, especially not any specific thing).
Also, remember the 2 senses of reduction mentioned at the start. The above is just what we know and what we can know. This doesn't mean that reduction doesn't exist in reality. It seems reasonable to say that things do reduce, because we've found many reductions so far, and many things once thought irreducible have been reduced. It is contrary to how we understand reality to work to say reduction isn't possible, that something happens spontaneously for no reason (except maybe on a quantum level, which is the furthest we can reduce things at this point). But someone may say "physical" reduction isn't possible (more on that below).
Regarding consciousness...
For consciousness in particular (which is what much of this discussion is ultimately about), we can point to plenty of apparent reductions.

We know very well when and how consciousness forms: it starts by people rubbing parts together in ways you may have learnt about in a "birds and the bees" talk, and we've seen every step of pregnancy.
We've identified which parts of the brain performs which functions.
We see how conscious thought causes brain activity in various parts of the brain through brain scans.
Damage to certain parts of the brain (whether through injury or disease) impedes or disables corresponding functions in consciousness.
We can reliably remove consciousness temporarily through physical means (cause unconsciousness with anesthesia), and verify that consciousness was removed (at least to the extent that the person appears to be unconscious and doesn't remember what happened during that time).
We can "reactivate" someone's consciousness (by shaking them to wake them up or injecting them with something), as long as their physical state enables them to regain consciousness.
We've developed and discovered physical substances (medicine and drugs) that reliably cause certain effects in consciousness.
We can see brain activity ceasing as a person loses consciousness upon death.
Resuscitation after death (after the heart stopped and after partial, but never full, ceasing of brain activity) often results impeded brain function.

This, in my opinion, makes an overwhelmingly strong case for consciousness reducing to brain activity, even if we don't fully understand every part of the above.
What about *physical* reduction, though?
Well... what is "physical"? What is non-physical?
As expanded on in another answer, I can't draw a coherent distinction between those things.
The reason I call myself a physicalist is purely because all the "non-physical" things people propose don't seem to exist, or they seem to reduce to things we both accept as physical. The means those people propose for investigating those things are unreliable, and when reliable means are used, their claims cannot be verified. If judged as we judge "physical" things, we would just conclude they do not exist, and indeed that is what I conclude, because I don't know of any other reliable means to judge things by.
If someone wants to adopt the burden of drawing a coherent categorical distinction between physical and non-physical, and then argue that both of those things exist, that would be their burden to meet.
As per my example above of a materialising being, it would indeed be theoretically possible to accept that our model of reality is significantly wrong, and to investigate, and to update it appropriately by accepting claims that were outside our model of reality (which, arguably, all claims are, until they are accepted). Whether any of this may involve accepting the existence of something "non-physical" is debatable, but not particularly meaningful to me. The point is that it would be supported by empirical evidence, which is lacking for claims currently labelled as "non-physical".
There has arguably already been significant shifts in our model of reality, e.g. accepting that stuff is made of atoms.
The debate around the physical / non-physical distinction (including Hempel's dilemma) may be somewhat of a red herring to distract from the lack of evidence for claims that people label as "non-physical".

This answer has a somewhat technical part that comes first. There is another part which tries to  explain the problem of reduction to people with no background in physics or chemistry.
Some strong claims are laid in Chapter 6 of the article Philosophy of Chemistry in the SEP.
As a preamble, I want to note that the article was written by Paul Needham and Robin Hendry and that they frequently cite from their own work in this chapter to corroborate their own claims. I have looked at some of these claims. The one claim that I found most troublesome was one of the most important chemical trends, the length of periods in the Periodic Table, cannot be derived from quantum mechanics, unless experimentally derived chemical information is specifically introduced (Scerri 1997). Troublesome because it lies at the heart of chemistry. I followed up on the literature and I was assured that Schrödinger’s equation for electrons gives a good explanation of how the main shells of the atom can contain a maximum of 2, 8, 18 or 32 electrons and hence explain the lengths of the periods. The debate is mostly about the details and that there are good, if computationally complex solutions (see Ostrovsky). The phrase 'cannot be derived' as used by the authors seems too strong and was not used by Scerri himself. Given the success of the reductionist view of quantum chemistry and ongoing work in the field, I would think that 'cannot be derived yet with certainty' would be a more appropriate formulation.
One of the most cited authors in the above article is philosopher of chemistry Eric Scerri and at the 4.10 timestamp in this video, he is asked whether chemistry can in principle be reduced to physics and the answer is... yes. He then asks if it is a good idea to teach chemistry as if a part of physics. I agree with him that this may not be the case. But that doesn't mean we should deny that chemistry is in principle reducible to physics.
The reason is that for most of chemistry the 'ab initio' explanation of the structure of a (complex) molecule is very difficult. In fact, nothing more complex than one electron molecules like H2+ can be fully calculated. In practice, we know from chemical analysis the structure of a molecule and are then able to approximate that structure with quantum chemistry.
Another example given by Hendry (and remember that the article is co-authored by Hendry) is that of chemical structure. He takes the example of two isomers (dimethyl ether and ethanol) and describes the different properties of these isomers. Every high school student with some chemistry under their belt knows that isomers with the same atoms can form structurally different atoms. The whole paragraph suggests a problem (where I honestly don't see one at all) and he concludes:

While he [Hendry] acknowledges that these facts are not incompatible with the claim that structure is reducible [sic!], Hendry argues that strong emergence is just as plausible an interpretation as reduction of the explanatory relationship between chemistry and quantum mechanics (2006b, 2010a).

If we take the Wikipedia definition of strong emergence:

Strong emergence describes the direct causal action of a high-level system on its components; qualities produced this way are irreducible to the system's constituent parts. The whole is other than the sum of its parts. It is argued then that no simulation of the system can exist, for such a simulation would itself constitute a reduction of the system to its constituent parts. Physics lacks well-established examples of strong emergence, unless it is interpreted as the impossibility in practice to explain the whole in terms of the parts.

Then I think strong emergence is totally uncalled for.
Of course, when we get at the level of physical properties like the solubility of a substance in water, we need explanations that look at the form of molecules and their configuration relative to each other, we look at Van der Waals forces. This is the domain of chemistry. To say, as Hendry does, that the Hamiltonians for the molecules are the same (as an approximation because we assume the atom nuclei fixed) and therefore don't explain anything about their physical properties, is trivial. This is because the spatial configuration of the atoms in the molecules are functional in explaining Van der Waals forces. This can be done in simulations and even though we cannot reduce this to the outcome of the individual Hamiltonians of said molecules, nobody in their right mind would deny that we we cannot in principle explain that the electrostatic forces or the fluctuating polarizations of nearby particles as explained by quantum mechanics, are in fact the reason of these different Van der Waals forces that will lead to differences in solubility of said molecules.
There is more, but I don't want to go into too much detail. I think there is something to be said about the epistemic reducibility and the ontological reducibility of chemistry to physics. There is more to be said about Nagel's very strict account of reduction. But I would rather try to give an analogy of what the problem is all about.
So I have come up with a toy model to try to explain this problem to people with no background in physics or chemistry. Suppose we want to reduce the economy of a village to the psychology of its inhabitants. To do that we take the price development of bread as an example. This price is determined by the  supply and demand of bread and is dependent on the psychology of the villagers who we will assume, as usual in economic theory, are rational economic agents, and who make up the economy of the village.
When the demand for bread is high, bakers feel like they could increase the price of their bread. When supply is high, customers feel like they could shop around for a baker that sells at a lower price and bakers have to adjust their prices accordingly.
It is therefore rational to assume that the economy reduces to the decisions the bakers and their customers make. It reduces, in other words, to their psychology. But now the philosophers of economy in the village will argue that this is not so. They will hold that psychology only accounts for the economic behaviour of a single person, given their financial situation and the price of bread. We cannot arrive at a law of supply and demand without knowledge of the market, the number of bakeries, the number of inhabitants, the cost of grain and what not. These are phenomena that are particular to the science of economy and of which we have no knowledge on the level of psychology. They will therefore maintain that the economy of the village is irreducible to the psychology of its villagers.
Yet, given our knowledge of our toy model, it is still very rational to claim that everything that happens with respect to the price development of bread is in principle reducible to the psychology of the individual. In the end, it is only individual decisions that make up the market. But in the narrower sense, it is hard to see how one could ‘predict’ the laws of supply and demand given only the psychology of the individual. In principle, maybe yes, but this is where we are. The laws of supply and demand were first derived from economic data, not from psychological analysis. The question is, however, if the laws of supply and demand make any sense without the knowledge that individual agents act according to a (folk) psychology which explains their hopes and desires (that is, cheap bread for customers and high profit for bakers).
Disclaimer: I am not an economist, nor a psychologist. I assume folk psyhology and basic supply and demand mechanics. I think it is a good model to convey the problems of reductionism.
